# postgres, restore database from commandline

Tags: postgresql

Trying to import a database.

Followed this documentation
Restore: $ psql -U {user-name} -d {desintation_db}-f {dumpfilename.sql}

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/how-to-backup-and-restore-postgres-database-using-pg_dump-and-psql/

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run `psql` from a shell, not from a `psql` instance.